# Horizontal Drag Gesture on Vertical ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have an app similar to most with a main view that scrolls vertically. On top of that, I have a horizontal drag gesture to pull out a side menu.

The issue I am running into when trying to drag the menu open is any vertical movement at all stops the horizontal gesture from working until the vertical movement has ended. So it is very difficult to get the horizontal gesture to activate.

I have tried using `.highPriorityGesture` and `.simultaneousGesture` but neither seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a minimumDistance on the Vertical gesture should fix it

```
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
```

Comment: How to add this to a ScrollView?